# Excel VBA Function Not Finding Exact Match in Array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have an array that contains "Hot Soup".  When I use the following function in an If statement to test whether "Soup" is found in the array, it returns as true:

```
Function FindInArray(StringToBeFound As Variant, ThisArray As Variant) As Boolean

  FindInArray = (UBound(Filter(ThisArray, StringToBeFound)) > -1)

End Function
```

A test:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim bool As Boolean

    myArray = Array("Hot Soup", "Vanilla")
    bool = FindInArray("Soup", myArray)
    MsgBox bool

End Sub
```

This returns true, and it is not.  Is there a way to return true ONLY if the match is exact?

Thanks!

Comment: You may need to iterate through the resulting array of the filter and check for exact match.

Comment: Aside from those in the question you can use this in your function `FindInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(StringToBeFound, ThisArray, 0))` instead of what you have.

Comment: ^^^ The above only works with a single dimension array.

Comment: you only need one line to display the behaviour   .... `MsgBox Filter(Array("Hot Soup", "Vanilla"), "Soup")(0)`

Comment: Scott Craner - thanks!  If you put your Application.Match option as an answer I will vote it as correct.  Thanks again!

Comment: jsotola - that was unhelpful.